# Is it possible to make it so that the "go to line" function remember the last entered value?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible in Visual Studio Code to make it so that the "go to line" functionality (CTRL-G) remember the last entered value?

Comment: You can use bookmarks extentions.

Comment: That's not even close :) I use bookmarks when I want to constantly jump between (usually) 2 points in my code. I just needed to see if there's some difference at a specific line of code in many files that I was closing and opening

Comment: Dunno, go create issue on github like "Feature request: go to line => remember last result".

Comment: Sounds like you just need some cli command for that task